# How to toggle (change multiple times) data by using useState and onClick in React?

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, toggle, use-state

In react
I have some data ("empty boxes") and a button. When I click on a button "empty boxes" changes to "full boxes". Next click nothing changes. ("full boxes" remains)
But I want toggle that, each click must show me "empty boxes" or "full boxes" in turn.
Can anyone help?

```
export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("empty boxes")
  const change = () => {
    setName("full boxes")
  }
  return (
   <main>
{name} 
<button onClick={change}>Change it!</button>
   </main>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should control your event by if

```
const change = () => {
if (name == "empty boxes")

  {setName("full boxes")}

else { setName("empty boxes")}
```

}

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much!